# Proving that if $M$ is a finitely generated and projective $R$ module, then $M$ is also finitely presented.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Since $M$ is finitely generated $R$ module, we have an epimorphism $\pi : F \to M$, such that $F= R^{(n)}$ where $n$ is a positive integer. On the other hand, since $M$ is a projective $R$ module we have by a well known property of projective modules that $M$ is isomorphic to some direct summand of $F$, that is, $M \cong F_{2}$ where $F= F_{1} \oplus F_{2}$. So we consider the following  canonical short exact sequence:

$$0 \to F_{1} \to F_{1} \oplus F_{2} \to F_{2} \to 0.$$

In order to prove that $M$ is a finitely presented $R$ module we need to show that $F=F_{1} \oplus F_{2}$ is a free and finitely generated module (we already know this is true since $F = R^{(n)}$), and we also need to show that $F_{1}$ is just finitely generated. Still I'm run out of ideas in order to argue that $F$ is finitely generated if $F$ is Noetherian we are done but its not the case. Is my train of thought for this proof OK? How can I argue $F_{1}$ being a submodule (direct summand) of $F$ is finitely generated?  Thanks!

Comment: Note that $F_1$ is an homomorphic image of $F$, hence is finitely generated.

Comment: Right! Havent see it but yes, since we have a canonical epimorhism $\pi: F \to F_{1}$ where $F$ is already finitely generated, then $F_{1}$ is also finitely generated, correct? @FabioLucchini

Answer (score 1):

Consider $P$ a finitely generated projective module. This means there exists a surjection $\pi :R^n\to P$ for some finite $n$.

Since $P$ is projective, this surjection splits, that is, there exists a map  $j: P\to R^n$ such that $\pi j = 1_P$, and the splitting lemma guarantees that the short exact sequence

$$0\longrightarrow K \longrightarrow R^n \longrightarrow P \longrightarrow  0$$
is isomorphic to the canonical short exact sequence

$$0\longrightarrow K \stackrel{j_1}\longrightarrow K\oplus P 
\stackrel{\pi_2}\longrightarrow P \longrightarrow  0.$$

In particular, there exists a projection $\pi_1 : R^n\cong K\oplus P\to K$, exhibiting the kernel of $\pi$ as a finitely presented module.